Speed up of the workflow: masking + global summing for 50 not-so-small tiles using terra R package
As a newbie of terra I am finding difficult to speed up a very simple task:
I have 50 tiles of 200 x 200 x 9000 (a list of SpatRaster).
I need to apply a mask to each tile and compute a global sum for each layer.
And repeat this for 6 different masks.
I was willing to use the function posted below, which works fine on a standard lapply loop.
As I understand it might not be worth to be parallelised since masking is involved: is that correct?
A serial slow approach follows, but any suggestion about how to speed up this process is highly welcome.
library(terra)
r10 <- terra::rast(nrow = 10, ncol = 10, nlyrs = 5, vals = 10, xmin = 0, xmax = 1, ymin = 0, ymax = 1)
r20 <- terra::rast(nrow = 10, ncol = 10, nlyrs = 5, vals = 20, xmin = 0, xmax = 1, ymin = 1, ymax = 2)
r30 <- terra::rast(nrow = 10, ncol = 10, nlyrs = 5, vals = 30, xmin = 1, xmax = 2, ymin = 0, ymax = 1)
r40 <- terra::rast(nrow = 10, ncol = 10, nlyrs = 5, vals = 40, xmin = 1, xmax = 2, ymin = 1, ymax = 2)

large.mask <- terra::rast(nrow = 20, ncol = 20, nlyrs = 1, vals = rep(c(1,0), 200), xmin = 0, xmax = 2, ymin = 0, ymax = 2)

rast.list <- list(r10, r20, r30, r40)

compute.layer.sum <- function(x, large.mask, code) {
    a <- terra::crop(large.mask, x)
    b <- terra::match(a, code)
    d <- terra::mask(x, b)
    terra::global(d, sum, na.rm = TRUE)
}

out <- lapply(rast.list, function(x) compute.layer.sum(x, large.mask = large.mask, code = 1))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              


On my machine your code is not reproducible. Several erros are returned. Also, I edited library(dplyr) in to import %>%, and changed fun(x) to function(x)(shorthand would be \(x)) to the lapply call.

I worry less about speed than getting killed on memory exhaustion, so this is an extended 'comment', not the answer for speed that you are looking for. Consider terra::window as a manner to handle your large.mask without croping, that does not create further datasets (crop objects) that may weight on available memory. While the below strives to follow your approach as above, some names and magnitudes have been changed to protect the innocent.
r10_9k <- rast(nrow = 200, ncol = 200, nlyrs = 9000, vals = 10, xmin = 0, xmax = 1, ymin = 0, ymax = 1)
r20_9k <- rast(nrow = 200, ncol = 200, nlyrs = 9000, vals = 20, xmin = 0, xmax = 1, ymin = 1, ymax = 2)
r30_9k <- rast(nrow = 200, ncol = 200, nlyrs = 9000, vals = 30, xmin = 1, xmax = 2, ymin = 0, ymax = 1) 
r40_9k <- rast(nrow = 200, ncol = 200, nlyrs = 9000, vals = 40, xmin = 1, xmax = 2, ymin = 1, ymax = 2) 
large.mask2 <- rast(nrow = 400, ncol = 400, nlyrs = 1, vals = rep(c(0,1), 20000), xmin = 0, xmax = 2, ymin = 0, ymax = 2)
df <- data.frame(sum.1 = rep(NA_real_, 9000), sum.2 = rep(NA_real_, 9000), sum.3 = rep(NA_real_, 9000), sum.4 = rep(NA_real_, 9000))
code = 1


As the extents of r10:r40 reside within the extent of large.mask2, the following is a plausible course
window(large.mask2) <- ext(r10_9k)
r10_match <- match(large.mask2, code)
r10_mask <- mask(r10_9k, r10_match)
df$sum.1 <- global(r10_mask, sum, na.rm = TRUE)
window(large.mask2) <- NULL
window(large.mask2) <- ext(r20_9k)
r20_match <- match(large.mask2, code)
r20_mask <- mask(r20_9k, r20_match)
df$sum.2 <- global(r20_mask, sum, na.rm = TRUE)
window(large.mask2) <- NULL
# rinse and repeat for further rN

head(df)
    sum   sum sum.3 sum.4
1 2e+05 4e+05    NA    NA
2 2e+05 4e+05    NA    NA
3 2e+05 4e+05    NA    NA
4 2e+05 4e+05    NA    NA
5 2e+05 4e+05    NA    NA
6 2e+05 4e+05    NA    NA

And those column names, ah well.

Good to know about terra::window, although I sadly confirm that it is not speeding up the process. I have no issues with memory, and the problem I have actually is with the (slow) disk I/O. I started more R sessions to process the data simultaneously to speed up a bit: I ended up with filling root filesystem with the increase of the /tmp folder. Not good...

Have a look at 'terraOptions()` and set where you'd like files to go that aren't going to fill a 'size restricted' part of your file structure, likely a directory you make in ~/home/USER. This is by session temporary. Also consider setting terraOptions(to_disk = TRUE, and created objects will be written to the directory even if not named. But, from 10k meter view, what is your data and what are we trying to do here?
